# VB HtmlAgilityPack Join String Node, Ignore Node Not Found

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I just need the following transformations like :

> ("c1", "c2", "c3", "c665", "c666") --> "c1, c2, c3, c665, c666">
>
> ("c1", c2, "c3", node c665 not found, node c666 not found) --> "c1, c2, c3"
>
> Skip c665 & c666 if node not found

if search results that appear are only 5 items from web, ignore next item

```
Imports System
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports System.Linq
                
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim Web As New HtmlWeb()
        Dim doc2 As New HtmlDocument()
        doc2 = Web.Load("https://download.cnet.com/s/pdf/")
        Try
            '' Categories (Single Node) 
            Dim Categories1 As HtmlNode = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='search-results']/a[1]/div/h4/div[1]")
            Dim c1 = Categories1.InnerText
            Dim Categories2 As HtmlNode = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='search-results']/a[2]/div/h4/div[1]")
            Dim c2 = Categories2.InnerText
            Dim Categories3 As HtmlNode = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='search-results']/a[3]/div/h4/div[1]")
            Dim c3 = Categories3.InnerText
            Dim Categories665 As HtmlNode = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='search-results']/a[665]/div/h4/div[1]")
            Dim c665 = Categories665.InnerText
            Dim Categories666 As HtmlNode = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='search-results']/a[666]/div/h4/div[1]")
            Dim c666 = Categories666.InnerText
            Dim array() As String = {c1, c2, c3, c665, c666}
            Dim Full As String = String.Join(", ", array.Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
                If (Categories1.InnerText.Contains("")) Then
                    Console.WriteLine (Full)
                End if
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XJKRiw

Comment: And why is `String.Join(", ", array.Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))` not working?

Comment: node c2 = null => result blank,, if c2 = delete => result show c1, c3,, i don't know T_T

Comment: Is the value `c2` actually NULL (AKA `Nothing`) or `"null"` (i.e., just a regular string)? Also, what exactly do you mean by `delete`?

Comment: c2 node not found, i mean skip node if not found, sorry i'm newbie

Comment: Try `Dim c2 = Categories2?.InnerText` (notice the `?`. You might also want to do the same with `c1` and `c3`).

Comment: Compilation error (line 14, col 0): The '?' character cannot be used here.
Compilation error (line 16, col 0): The '?' character cannot be used here.
Compilation error (line 18, col 0): The '?' character cannot be used here.
Compilation error (line 19, col 0): 'c1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Compilation error (line 19, col 0): 'c2' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Compilation error (line 19, col 0): 'c3' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: If you show us the page html (you can hide the data) we could help you fix it.

Comment: wait a second...

Comment: ..... anybody ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectSingleNode` will return `Nothing` if the node was not found. You can check for that and not do any further processing of it.

I notice that you have the same code repeated except for a small string - that is usually a good candidate for putting the code in a loop.

I guess you are using an older version of Visual Studio and that is why the `?` operator was not available to you, so I'll show an example without newer features:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Web As New HtmlWeb()
    Dim doc2 As New HtmlDocument()
    doc2 = Web.Load("https://download.cnet.com/s/pdf/")

    Dim indices = {1, 2, 3, 665, 666}
    Dim results As New List(Of String)

    For Each ix In indices
        Dim xpathQuery = String.Format("//div[@id='search-results']/a[{0}]/div/h4/div[1]", ix)
        Dim c = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpathQuery)

        If c IsNot Nothing Then
            results.Add(c.InnerText)
        End If

    Next

    If results.Count > 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", results))
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Nothing found.")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Outputs:

> PDF Download, PDF ReDirect, Free PDF to Word